# set Video as Ringtone in Samsung Galaxy s4

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4, ringtone

Is that possible to set Video as a ringtone in Samsung Galaxy S4? It's perfectly working in my NOKIA Lumia 630. But no in Samsung Galaxy S4.

Any ways if you have. Thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- First convert video into mp3 using third party app like  [convert video to mp3](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=tmn.videotomp3) and than set ringtone.

OR

- Simply change the extension of file from (.mp4/.3gp/.flv/.avi) to .mp3 and set it as a ringtone

Comment: No. I want to set as Video. When any call arrived play that Video song.

Comment: @MD I don't think Android supports video format as ringtone. Converting to audio file should be the solution, as explained on this answer.

Comment: @AndrewT. That's what i am talking about?

Comment: @AndrewT. I think Android and  iOS phone not support that feature. Nokia is best on This.